# Adding columns to a dropdown Spring MVC

Tags: java, javascript, spring, model-view-controller

I currently have the following code

```
<td align="left" class="colText" id="custName">Customer Name <td>
<td>
    <form:select path="skName" class="textbox3" id="custName" >  
    <form:option value="${form.skName }" label="Name – SK Number" id="custName "/>
    <form:options items="${custName}" itemValue="skName"  itemLabel="displayName"/>
    </form:select> 
</td>
```

I want my dropdown to display 2 columns with a header over each. One is displaying the Customer Name and the other the SK Number. I currently can only display the Customer Name in the dropdown.

Comment: So... what happened when you tried making this change? ...you *did* try, didn't you?

Comment: The current code only displays the Customer Name in the dropdown.